# Dropbox is not letting me move its storage off the (small) eMMC

Tags: ext4, dropbox, lmde

I'm having problems with a fresh install of LMDE on an acer Travelmate (TMB117 M C587) that has a 32gb eMMC drive and a 1tb hdd. specifically, I can't move dropbox's storage off the eMMC onto the 1tb drive.

the error reads

```
To sync your Dropbox, move your Dropbox folder to a partition with a >compatible File System. Dropbox is compatible with Ext4.
```

which leads me to conclude either Dropbox has lost it... or far more likely, I messed up somewhere along the way. Or something else entirely is going on with my laptop that I'm just missing.

`parted -l` and `/etc/fstab` both show that both relevant drives are formated to ext4.

`parted -l` *does* show two other drives (`/dev/mmcblk0boot0` and `/dev/mmcblk0rpmb`) that are lacking in a proper file system. Given the size, I'm operating on the assumption that they're read-only memory on the motherboard for firmware type things (possibly the TPM module?) and not something I should be trying to 'fix' with a `makefs.ext4` or similar.

I'm also trying to figure out why dropbox would care about them at all... or why it would be kicking up that error.

`sudo parted -l`:

```
Model: ATA ST1000LM035-1RK1 (scsi)
Blockquote
Disk /dev/sda: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name     Flags
 1      1049kB  1000GB  1000GB  ext4         primary


Error: /dev/mmcblk0rpmb: unrecognised disk label
Warning: Error fsyncing/closing /dev/mmcblk0rpmb: Input/output error
Retry/Ignore? i                                                           
Model: Generic SD/MMC Storage Card (sd/mmc)
Disk /dev/mmcblk0rpmb: 4194kB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: unknown
Disk Flags: 

Error: /dev/mmcblk0boot0: unrecognised disk label
Model: Generic SD/MMC Storage Card (sd/mmc)                               
Disk /dev/mmcblk0boot0: 4194kB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: unknown
Disk Flags: 

Error: /dev/mmcblk0boot1: unrecognised disk label
Model: Generic SD/MMC Storage Card (sd/mmc)                               
Disk /dev/mmcblk0boot1: 4194kB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: unknown
Disk Flags: 

Model: MMC M52532 (sd/mmc)
Disk /dev/mmcblk0: 31.3GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name  Flags
 1      1049kB  538MB   537MB   fat32                 boot, esp
 2      538MB   29.2GB  28.7GB  ext4
 3      29.2GB  31.3GB  2056MB  linux-swap(v1)
```

`/etc/fstab`

```
# UNCONFIGURED FSTAB FOR BASE SYSTEM
proc    /proc   proc    defaults        0       0
# /dev/mmcblk0p1
UUID=1473-7E8C  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults        0       0
# /dev/mmcblk0p2
UUID=18e97241-975e-4cb8-8a36-ca7298d2f255       /       ext4   
rw,errors=remount-ro    0       1
# /dev/mmcblk0p3
UUID=9475a0d3-967d-41bb-a33c-67862702548e       swap    swap    sw      >0       0
# /dev/sdb1
UUID=c0ee208c-1a84-4457-a887-0eecd6876e3a       /cake   ext4    rw,errors=remount-ro    0       0
```

Answer (score 2):

Dropbox requires a filesystem that allows the use of user-specified extended attributes. Run `getfattr *` in the Dropbox directory: you'll see that all the files have an extended attribute, named either `user.com.dropbox.attrs` or `user.com.dropbox.attributes` depending on Dropbox version.

To allow the use of extended attributes, you can either add the `user_xattr` mount option to `/etc/fstab` for your /dev/sda1, or (more convenient for external drives) you can add the option to the filesystem itself with `tune2fs -o +user_xattr /dev/sda1`. You should probably unmount the filesystem for making this modification: it will take effect the next time you mount it.

[Here is a more definitive list of the requirements of modern Dropbox on Linux.](https://askubuntu.com/a/1087376/769591)

Comment: Thank you for your help. this was exactly the issue.

Comment: See also summary of possible reasons here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1087376/29252

Comment: @FlorianEchtler: thanks, added the link to my answer.